# Ts Missing definition from union type and class

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

Hi why ts show wrong information when we have this kind of pattern?

```
class A {
    Renderer = RendererA;
}
class B {
    Renderer = RendererB;
}

const RendererA = (prop:{instance?:A}) => {};
const RendererB = (prop:{instance?:B}) => {};

declare const Test:A|B;
// should accept instance A|B And Point to RendererA & RendererB, why only RendererA ?

Test.Renderer({instance:Test});
```

Why when trigger `Test.Renderer` is tell me `RendererA` only ! and not `RendererA & RendererB` where they can handle A|B ! ?

[tsPlayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false#code/FAYwNghgzlAECCsDewCQAlApgOwCaYCdDYBeWLPQw%20AbjQHp6AFAgSwFtWAXVgN01KwWHbn0y1gAX1CQYsAELI0FfEQKCVVAvLqpGwzj36CDo-jqnBQAe2xQu5HKuqCAFAAcC19wC4krOy4IbBBMAH4feEkASlIAPiVUIi4AVwJsWGwUsDA6STobQMdKNUUyDy9ff0Dg0Ij5GPjE5LSMrJypApBbeyE2QzFEcs9vP14IrPYAI0JGkgSUJMxU9MzssE6rbqLTI0wy2ArRpHGfezZsAHM5hbQW1faN-Kt8cAgiWG3egBVMe0iAD4WRiwKAAC2s2VwsAgIFC7gcAXstQE8CBCDwQmsAQcXGsxWcBEQADICVp5FZfvYAHSaNSuarIkKYHxUrgxGiwYCMNnU3ZiBm8HyPDlAA)
And image if needed

[image]

Comment: Looks like `A` and `B` are structurally identical so the compiler treats them as synonymous types. If you want something else you should distinguish them structurally, say by adding a property to one or both that makes them incompatible.

Comment: I assume it's duck typing,  if it looks like a duck, quacks like a duck, it's probably a duck.

Comment: if i add more field, it continu to tell me it point to `RendererA` only and missing the `RendererB` , where is there ! 
What will the approach in this case to allow `Test.Renderer({instance:Test})` without add bunch of condition for narrowing !?